# How to hide the Value of a Slider in jsxgraph?

Tags: slider, jsxgraph

I want the number, that shows the current value of a slider, not to be seen in the graph. How can I do that?

var PX = b1.create('slider', [[3,8],[8,8],[-2,0,2]],{label:{visble:false},name:'Arbeitskoeffizient K'});

doesn't do it.

Best,
Carl

Answer (score 0):

The attribute responsible for hiding the text of the slider is `withLabel`. At the time being it is immutable, i.e. can not be changed later on. An example is:

```
var s = board.create('slider', [[-3, 2], [2, 2], [-10, 1, 10]], {
    withLabel: false
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/aLcr01xt/